# Send data to DB and get back via AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The following code works properly and I am using it 'cause I need to update some notes in DB without refreshing a page. **But what have to do when I need in the same event get some data back?**

**index.php** where change should occur

```
<?php
$s = $GET['...']
$p = $GET['...']
print '
 <form id="notesForm">
  <textarea name="c">'.$note.'</textarea>
  <input type="text" value="LAST_CHANGE_NEED_GIVE_BACK_FROM_DB">
  <input type="hidden" name="s" value="'.$s.'">
  <input type="hidden" name="p" value="'.$p.'">
  <input type="submit" value="save note">
  <div id="response"></div>
</form>
';
?>
```

**script** which is posting data to live_notes.php and probably should be changed because of the goal

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#notesForm').submit(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#response').html("<b>saving...</b>");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'notes/live_notes.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#response').html(data);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("bad luck");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**notes/live_notes.php**

```
<?php
$s = $_POST['s'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

// connecting DB

mysql_query("
UPDATE `poznamky`
SET
    last_change = now(),
    page = '$p',
    content = '$c'
WHERE
    page = '$p';
");
```

**any idea?**

Comment: You want to return some data from notes/livenotes.php?

Comment: Actually, need to reload some data from db in the same event and really don't know how to do it...:/

Comment: you want to perform update then select some data from db and return to  ajax?

Comment: Yes, exactly and print them on the screen.

Comment: Any idea what I have to do? I'm newer about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$s = $_POST['s'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

// connecting DB

$blnSuccess = mysql_query("
UPDATE `poznamky`
SET
    last_change = now(),
    page = '$p',
    content = '$c'
WHERE
    page = '$p';
");

if($blnSuccess){
echo "success";
}
else {
echo "not success!";
}
```

in your jquery :

```
.done(function(data){
            $('#response').html(data); 
}
```

data have `success` or `not success!` which return as ajax response.

**Update**
If you want to return some data from database then:

```
$result = mysql_query("
   select * 
      from `poznamky`
");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['content'];
}
```

Then it will return all `content` field from `poznamky` table into data in ajax.

Comment: Thank you for ur time and response Awlad :)

Comment: Well, you said "which return as ajax response, but how can I require specific column instead of echoing (not) success. Isn't Sarah's response something what I need?? Thanks

Comment: Ops... Im sorry.. .] Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$s = $_POST['s'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

// connecting DB

$OK = mysql_query("
UPDATE `poznamky`
SET
    last_change = now(),
    page = '$p',
    content = '$c'
WHERE
    page = '$p';
");

$id = mysql_insert_id();
$res = mysql_query("select * from poznamky where id = $id");


$data = mysql_fetch_array($res);

//Print raw or JSON of $data like json_encode($data) etc
```

Comment: I would like to, but have not enough reputation .)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return something back then in your notes.php you can do something like this:

```
$s = $_POST['s'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$c = $_POST['c'];

// connecting DB

mysql_query("
UPDATE `poznamky`
SET
    last_change = now(),
    page = '$p',
    content = '$c'
WHERE
    page = '$p';
");

$select = "//use your select query and loop here and get all data in this variable";

exit($select);
```

and in jquery:

```
.done(function(data){
           //data has the response. You can do whatever you want to do with it.
}
```